# Using Required Expression and Required Field Validators in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am having trouble validating the use inputs once the calculate button is clicked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. All text fields must be validated using the Validation Controls and should include a summary to show errors. I would like the error messages to appear in my lblMessage.Text but nothing is showing once Calculate is clicked. (SIDE NOTE: I also cannot get my Clear button to reset the textboxes to NULL. Help with that would be great too)

HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div>
                <img src="images/header.jpg" alt="Get Fit" title="GetFit" width="100%"/>
        </div>

        <h1>Body Mass Index Calculator</h1>

            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style4">Enter your first name:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style5">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style7">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style4">Enter your age: 
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style6"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style5">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style7">
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="cv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAge" Type="Integer" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid age" >*</asp:CompareValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style4">Enter your email: 
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style6"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" TabIndex="3"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style5">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style7">
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid email" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style4">Enter your height:&nbsp;
                        </td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHeight" runat="server" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    <td class="auto-style5">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblHeight" runat="server" Text="INCHES"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style7">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtHeight" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="You must enter a valid height">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style4">Enter your weight:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtWeight" runat="server" TabIndex="5"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style5">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWeight" runat="server" Text="POUNDS"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style7">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtWeight" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="You must enter a valid weight">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <br />
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate BMI" align="center" TabIndex="6"/>
                        &nbsp;
                        <span style="color:darkblue;">|</span>&nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" align="center" TabIndex="7"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <br />
        <table align="center">   
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h1>Your BMI:</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBMI" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" TabIndex="8"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2>This means you are:
                        </h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtResults" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" TabIndex="9"></asp:TextBox>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

ASPX.VB

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Sub ClearAll()
        txtName.Text = ""
        txtAge.Text = ""
        txtEmail.Text = ""
        txtHeight.Text = ""
        txtWeight.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        ClearAll()
        'txtName.Text = String.Empty
        'txtAge.Text = String.Empty
        'txtEmail.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Calculate()
    End Sub


    Public Sub Calculate()
        'Name
        If txtName.Text = String.Empty Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter a name."
        Else
        End If

        'Age
        If txtAge.Text = String.Empty Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter an age."
        Else
        End If

        'Email
        If txtEmail.Text = String.Empty Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter an email."
        Else
        End If

        'Height
        If txtHeight.Text = String.Empty Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter a height."
        Else
        End If

        'Weight
        If txtWeight.Text = String.Empty Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter a height."
        Else
        End If

        Dim Result As Double ' Declare "Result" as a Double.
        Dim Rounded_Result As Double

        Result = txtWeight.Text / (txtHeight.Text * txtHeight.Text) * 703 ' BMI Calculation.

        Rounded_Result = Math.Round(Result, 1) ' Round result to 1 decimal place.
        txtBMI.Text = Rounded_Result.ToString ' Display BMI using lblBMI.

        BMI_Message(Rounded_Result) 'Send Rounded BMI result to Sub BMI_Message.

    End Sub

    Public Sub BMI_Message(ByVal BMI_Value As Double)
        Select Case BMI_Value
            Case 0.0 To 18.5
                txtResults.Text = "Underweight"
            Case 18.6 To 24.9
                txtResults.Text = "Normal Weight"
            Case 25.0 To 29.9
                txtResults.Text = "Overweight"
            Case Is >= 30.0
                txtResults.Text = "Obese"
            Case Else
                txtResults.Text = "Unable to Determin BMI"
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you consider to apply client side validation as well?

Comment: yes. I have applied RegularExpressionValidator and RequiredFieldValidator but they do not seem to work. I did add the ValidationSettings to Web.config as well.

Comment: you can check form validation on form submit like

if(!$('form').valid())
{
// Do your Stuff
  return false; 
}